# I'm drawing a UML use case diagram for a shopping site, should 'Manage shopping cart' be included?

Tags: uml, use-case

What kind of behaviors should be included in the use case diagram?

Comment: "Manage shopping cart" probably shouldn't be added, but "remove item from shopping cart", "update quantity of item in shopping cart", etc. might should be.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself what's the added value of a shopping site. At first it will be "Present item". Next you will likely have "Sell item". Whether you do that with a cart or some other means is likely irrelevant. Usage of a shopping cart is an implementation detail. Even if you have a requirement "A shopping cart must be used", this is only part of an implementation. The real use cases are the first two. There might be more (cross sales, advertisement, etc...) you need to show. But "manage shopping cart" is definitely no use case. It simply does not add any value. Also adding or removing items from a cart does not have a real value, except you define playing with the cart as some entertainment (which I doubt).